# errorbar function in matlab - issue with positioning

Tags: matlab, errorbar

I'm using the errorbar function to plot the 95% confidence interval of my model predictions. I have the upper and lower position of where the "errorbar" tick should be. When I use the errorbar function however, these ticks are not at the required position. Please see below, I highly appreciate your help in advance!

```matlab
% data for errorbars
data = [-0.329764340000000;-0.374996630000000;-0.279023200000000;-0.366639140000000;0.347093700000000;0.545207860000000;0.751462400000000;-0.829505260000000;0.829507770000000;-0.545235100000000;0.524703500000000;0.232506130000000;-0.403305050000000;0.397193100000000];

% upper and lower ticks (positions) of the CI / errorbars
lower_CI = [-0.584740242855886;-0.570326581039562;-0.517823465974172;-0.629680037764874;-0.246945265039860;0.0562831850081804;0.360917757402951;-0.975194052079753;0.732974670525949;-0.698941828936124;-0.125875916733751;-0.277119510479645;-0.574489102702906;-0.115446583316303];
upper_CI = [0.147697669032193;0.0388520624922168;0.314905648112612;0.166970294864421;0.590855094796161;0.812980025737368;0.831301062393713;-0.701031711901664;0.985337808304139;-0.0585632559357397;0.700283292166636;0.563252495614094;0.166863127706487;0.708490555044120];

figure;
a = bar(data);
hold on
er = errorbar((1:14)',data,lower_CI,upper_CI, '.', 'vertical');  
er.Color = [0 0 0];
hold off
```

Answer (score 0):

As described [in the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/errorbar.html#d123e364826), the syntax `errorbar(x,y,neg,pos)` interprets `neg` and `pos` as the lengths of the error bar below and above `y`. So you should get the right plot with:

```matlab
a = bar(data);
hold on
er = errorbar((1:14)', data, data-lower_CI, upper_CI-data, '.');
er.Color = [0 0 0];
```